# Unity Lock width of game view

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 2d portrait game where the width of the screen makes a big difference. Ideally, I'd be able to lock width the main camera and the height would be changed based on device (the iPhone X, for example, would get a lot more content than an IPad because it's taller). I've tried messing around with the viewport settings and they seem similar to what I'm looking for, but not quite right. Is there a way to do this? Currently, my game scales both height and width and really messes somethings up.

Comment: For UI , you cant add "Canvas Scaler" to canvas and setting that

Comment: @TimChang thanks for the suggestion, however, I am using a camera with some 2d objects and not a canvas in this scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [orthographicSize](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-orthographicSize.html) is half the size of the vertical viewing volume

```
orthographicSize = height / 2
```

The [aspect ratio](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-aspect.html) (width divided by height).

```
aspect = width / height
```

Got

```
orthographicSize = width / aspect / 2
```

So what you need to do is define a fixed width, change the camera's orthographicSize property when the game starts (or orientation changes).

Comment: Got it working perfectly, thanks for your answer, saved me a ton of time.